# Can I make a variable universally available to each page in a view controller file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a viewController file in my application where I will pass variables into the front end of my application. However, I have certain variables that need to go in each page. Instead of repeating my code over and over, is there a way to pass a variable into each page?

In the example below, I define `cruiseLines` for `exports.getIndex`. But I have the same exact code in `exports.aboutUs` and `exports.shipDetails`, and so on and so on. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
exports.getIndex = async (req, res, next) => {
  // 1) Get tour data from Collection
  const ships = await Ship.find().sort({ shipName: 1 });
  const cruiseLines = await Ship.distinct('cruiseLine');
  const reviewCount = await Review.countDocuments();
  // 2) Build template
  // 3) Render the template from the tour data from step 1

  res.status(200).render('main', {
    title: 'Welcome',
    ships,
    reviewCount,
    cruiseLines,
  });
};
```

Comment: Is it just that one variable `cruiseLines` that you'd like to reuse?

Comment: Right now, yes. But it would be neat if I could do it for others as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a factory service and use that in your code. Something like this.

```
// ShipSevice.js
const getData = async () => { // you can rename the method
 try {
   const ships = await Ship.find().sort({ shipName: 1 });
   const cruiseLines = await Ship.distinct('cruiseLine');
   const reviewCount = await Review.countDocuments();
   return { ships, cruiseLines, reviewCount }
 } catch(err) {
   return {}
 }
}

module.exports = { getData }
```

```
const { getData } = require('relative-path/ShipSevice');

exports.getIndex = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // 1) Get tour data from Collection
    const { ships, cruiseLines, reviewCount } = await getData()
    // 2) Build template
    // 3) Render the template from the tour data from step 1

    res.status(200).render('main', {
      title: 'Welcome',
      ships,
      reviewCount,
      cruiseLines,
    });
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: 'failed to fetch the'})
  }
};
```

Comment: Good answer!  And then the `ShipService` could potentially be improved when desired by implementing a caching strategy.